# Backbone.js instance vs class variables

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having some confusion about instance and class variables. I made a fiddle to display something that seems inconsistent to me.

https://jsfiddle.net/njcfm4n8/1/

I'm familiar with the problem of declaring an array as a subclass property, it should be done in the `initialize` function, otherwise the array is shared among all instances. The fiddle demonstrates that. However, why is the `number` property not shared as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per muistooshort and maris' comments, the array happens to work like a class property because it is a reference type. That array really is shared among the instances of your model, but this is more a quirk of javascript and not the intended way to create class variables with Backbone.

An integer on the other hand is a primitive type, along with booleans and strings, and javascript does not pass references to these types but copies them instead.

Arrays, objects, and functions are reference types, while integers, booleans, null and undefined are value types. You can learn more about it here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm

If you want to make use of class properties, then this section of the Backbone docs is relevant: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

> extendBackbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties])
>
> To create a Model class of your own, you extend Backbone.Model and provide instance properties, as well as optional classProperties to be attached directly to the constructor function.

I've forked your jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zn6bu4uf/3/ with this code:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {foo: 0})

console.log(myModel.foo); // 0
myModel.foo++;
console.log(myModel.foo); // 1

var test1 = new myModel();
var test2 = new myModel();

test1.constructor.foo++;
test1.constructor.foo++;

test2.constructor.foo++;

console.log(test1.constructor.foo) // 4
console.log(test2.constructor.foo) // 4
```

Comment: I think you're being distracted by the erroneous "class variable" terminology. The real issue is that calling `push` on an array in the prototype modifies the array in-place but using `++` on a number in the prototype breaks out of the prototype (i.e. copies the new value to the instance without changing the value in the prototype).

Comment: @muistooshort You're right, thank you. While the array appears to work as a class variable, this is because it's an object and javascript uses references to objects instead of copying them. So it really is shared across classes, but not intentionally.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: More correct to say that boolean, int is value types and object and array is reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone add your properties (`n` and `arr`) to `myModel` prototype.

Because of that all `myModel` objects has `n` and `arr` in their `__proto__` and can access to them.

Array shared among objects because there is no assignment to place where array stored. Push mutates array itself.

But increment actually creating new value and then assigning it to object.

From spec:
 `test1.n++` will actually do this

1. get property `n` from object `test1` (if its not there search in `test1.__proto__` ... ) and save it virtual variable `old_val`.
2. set virtual variable `new_val` to `old_val + 1`
3. set value of property `n` in object "test1" to value of `new_val`
4. return `old_val`

By spec step 3 not checking initial location of property `n`. It will add new property to `test1`.

spec

- [post increment evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
- [get and put value to object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue)